# New computer build does not start

Tags: boot, computer-building

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [building a new pc - no display, no beeps](https://superuser.com/questions/105919/building-a-new-pc-no-display-no-beeps)

I just built a new computer with a new (empty) harddisk.

When I turn it on, the monitor is black (no signals), and there is no beeps at all.

I found this unusual. Any suggestions on what I should do/try?

More info:

- Motherboard is Gigabyte P67A UD3-B3
- Video card is Gigabyte Radeon 5770
- Motherboard LEDs, fans, harddisk were on
- I have plugged in the speaker cable from the case to the motherboard
- Monitor was plugged in (obviously)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [building a new pc - no display, no beeps](http://superuser.com/questions/105919/building-a-new-pc-no-display-no-beeps) or [New build won't boot: some fans turning, no beep or video](http://superuser.com/questions/66790/new-build-wont-boot-some-fans-turning-no-beep-or-video)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, and easiest options, remove and reseat the RAM modules and graphics card.  Make sure that the graphics card has the power connector fitted.

If that does not work I would next look at taking the heatsink and fan off the CPU and ensure that the CPU pins (fitted on the mobo for an LGA CPU) are not bent or distorted.  Finally make absolutely certain the CPU is fitted in the correct orientation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Mokubai and everyone! (+1 to all for the helpful suggestions)
I didn't notice this graphic card has a power slot! My first graphic card that needs that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if all wires are connected. Especially check the power for the Motherboard. Sometimes it has a large one and a small one and people sometimes forget to connect the smaller one. (also check the power to the video card)
2. It seems like your motherboard supports multiple Video cards. Try to insert yours in another slot. (check manual of your motherboard)

Answer (score 2):

Did you get the right kind of power supply for that motherboard? is the extra power (12v) cable attached? is it in the right position?

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that the monitor does not simply need to be toggled (check the buttons) between analog and digital. That happens to me with my Samsung monitors.